# Log failed username to txt file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Trying to capture the username entered from login control username textbox and write to separate text file for review. I need to find out what is being entered when users enter wrong username. I assume this needs to be done in code behind and can't be accomplished in asp.net control?

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" Width="760px">
     <LayoutTemplate>

                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 760px">

                         <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                                 <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label></td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                     ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                             </td>

                             <td align="right">
                                 <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label></td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                     ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                             </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                 <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1" /></td>
                         </tr>
                          </table>
                         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 760px">
                             <tr>
                             <td style="height: 16px; width: 346px; text-align: center;">
                                 <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal></td>

                             <td align="center" style="color: red; height: 16px; text-align: right;">
                                 <asp:HyperLink ID="ForgotPassword" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot Password?</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;</td>
                             </tr>
                         </table>
     </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: Personally I'd look at using the Windows Event Log to log any debug info or errors - it's just easier than trying to set something up yourself. If you do want to do this though, just look up "c# write text file" - trhe only difference for ASP.NET is that you need to make sure you've given the IIS user appropriate permissions.

Comment: this is on a hosted site, i don't have access to logs - I write to text file, just not sure how to trigger event or get textbox value (its also in vb.net not c#)

Comment: Ah, fair enough then - assuming they've given you access to create text files on the server underneath your own root folder you should be OK.

Comment: yea I have written to text before (stream reader) but not sure how to obtain value since its within controls - page source gives it: `id="ctl00_LoginView2_Login1_UserName"`

Comment: Added answer for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to handle this in your code behind. The best place for this would probably be the login button click handler:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Request.Form["UserName"];
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~") + "debug.txt";

    using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(username);
    }
}
```

Not tested, but it's a fairly simple operation all in all. Obviously this will only write the LAST attempted login into the file, it won't keep a running log. You just need to change the write to an append for that of course.

---

**EDIT:**

Whoops, poor reading comprehension on my part. VB.NET version:

```
Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim username As String = Request.Form("UserName")
    Dim filepath As String = Server.MapPath("~") + "debug.txt"

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(filepath)
        writer.WriteLine(username)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks - I think that is what I need, will the "loginButton_Click" interfere with the existing behavior of the current page. I currently don't have a vb page and would be adding to existing asp only page?

Comment: I'm afraid the best I can give you is "it shouldn't". If you have any javascript on the page there could be problems, especially if you're using javascript redirects or modifying on click behaviors. All you can do is keep your eyes peeled for any problems really.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have marked the question resolved.